# Powershell, Clean up files older dan x days - prevent NTFS junction points

Tags: powershell

I have a script that cleans up files and folders older then an x amount of days but i have to make it a bit more secure. The script as it is if someone created a link to for instance program files everything in that location also gets deleted. How can i secure my script against junction points

```
$path = "\\server\D$\Temp"
$items = get-childitem $path -Force -Recurse 

foreach($item in $items)
{
            $subitems = get-childitem -recurse -path $item.fullname
            foreach($subitem in $subitems)
            {
                if($subitem.lastwritetime -lt (date).adddays(-4))
                {
                    $filename = $subitem.fullname
                    if($filename -ne $null)
                    {
                        #Use below code to specify file type


                            "Remove item: " + $filename + " - " + $subitem.lastwritetime
                            remove-item $filename -recurse -WhatIf


                }
             }
        }
        $subitems_after = get-childitem -recurse -path $item.fullname
        if($subitems_after.Count -eq 0)
        {
            "Remove item: " + $item
            remove-item $item.FullName -WhatIf
        }

}
```

Comment: Hi there!  We're not a free script writing service.  Don't worry, lots of new users seem to make this mistake.  To get our help with this, please edit your question to include the research you've done, the things you've tried already (and what the results were).

Comment: Maybe this will help get you started: [Test in PowerShell code if a folder is a junction point?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311105/test-in-powershell-code-if-a-folder-is-a-junction-point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following script , it may filter Mount Point folders out and list common folders (you can also add time filter in that function or do it later ):

```
 function dir_NoMP ( $i ) {
        #check if it is a mount point folder
        $z = ( (get-item $i).Attributes -band [IO.FileAttributes]::ReparsePoint )

        #if it it not an empty folder call function itself
        if ( ($x =(Get-ChildItem $i -Directory ).fullname) -and (!$z ) ) { 

         #if it is a mount point , filter it out .
         $x | foreach {if ( !( (get-item $_).Attributes -band [IO.FileAttributes]::ReparsePoint ) ) {$_} } ;

         foreach ($y in $x) { dir_NoMP $y } }

    }  
    dir_nomp "d:\test"
```

After that you can do what you want for these listed folders .

Comment: It works thanks one problem left :( location has more then 260 chars so have to find another solution but thanks for youre help paul